# Why does not my function math.abs return true?

Tags: javascript

The function timeout decides if the absolute difference of the given dates (date1 and date2), is larger than the given absolute difference so it needs to return true if the difference between date1 and date2 is greater than the parameter timeLimit

I coded the following:

but in my test files, (1) and (2) still fails but the other passes and I dont know why. If I change the

```
 return Math.abs(date1 - date2) > limiet;
```

to

```
 return Math.abs(date1 - date2) < limiet;
```

then (1) and (2) passes but the other fail like below. how can I code it that everything is passed?

```js
function timeout(date1, date2, timeLimit) {
  const limiet = timeLimit * 60000;
  return Math.abs(date1 - date2) > limiet;
}

console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-09-01T08:30:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T11:30:00"), 60), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-09-01T11:30:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T08:30:00"), 60), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-09-01T11:30:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T08:30:00"), 190), "should return true")
console.log(1,timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), -5), "should return true")
console.log(2,timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), -1), "should return true")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 0), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 1), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 2), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 3), "should return true")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Math.abs the limiet too

Also you had a logical error in your (2) - you did not have more than one minute's difference and you have < not <= so we need a difference

```js
const ms2MMSS = ms => {   let minutes = Math.floor(ms / 60000);   let seconds = ((ms % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);  return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds; }

function timeout(date1, date2, timeLimit) {
  const limiet = Math.abs(timeLimit * 60000);
  console.log(ms2MMSS(limiet),ms2MMSS(Math.abs(date1.getTime()-date2.getTime())));
  return Math.abs(date1 - date2) < Math.abs(limiet);
}

console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-09-01T08:30:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T11:30:00"), 60), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-09-01T11:30:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T08:30:00"), 60), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-09-01T11:30:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T08:30:00"), 190), "should return true")
console.log(1,timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), -5), "should return true")
console.log(2,timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:00:00"), -2), "should return true")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 0), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 1), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 2), "should return false")
console.log(timeout(new Date("2019-08-31T23:59:00"), new Date("2019-09-01T00:01:00"), 3), "should return true")
```